# Flycheck does not find .h file

Tags: flycheck, c

I am using Flycheck for my syntax highlighting which have been working out great when working with all header and source files in one directory.

I recently decided to add some unit tests to test my code which I added another directory for. The projects compiles and runs without problems. My problem is that in the `test/Formula-test.cpp` file when i `#include "Formula.h"` a header from the `src/Formula.h` folder flycheck can't seem to find it. I get the "error" `'Formula.h' file not found (c/c++-clang)`.

My project structure looks like this:

```
.
├── build
│   └── compile_commands.json
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   └── googletest
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── Formula.cpp
│   ├── Formula.h
│   ├── main.cpp
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Formula-test.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

Is there any configuration or package that can fix this?

Here is my full config file: https://github.com/Zeppan/configs/blob/master/.emacs

Comment: Try to write ```#include "../src/Formula.h``` or add the src path in a .dir-locals.el file

Comment: It did work with `#include "../src/Formula.h` but it doesn't look very nice (good quick-fix however). Is there some way to make flycheck dependent on the `CMakeLists.txt`?


I read that you could create a `.clang_complete` file but I didn't find any information of how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you may configure flycheck with what you need - see flycheck group of variables. But that may not be the best idea, since your path changes in another project. The package `cmake-ide` could instead manage all flycheck paths for your project and adds also compilation command.

About a `.clang-complete` file, here it is my version:

```
-DDEBUG
-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/
-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/
-I/usr/local/opt/boost/include/
-I/Users/your-name/Path-to-proj/
```

I use the above and a .dir-locals.el file. The reason for me was that I use eglot + clangd, and this package (eglot) disable flycheck in favour of flymake (seems actually there is a wave of replacing flycheck with flymake...)

Comment: Thanks! The cmake-ide package worked out great!

It does however complains about stuff in the google-test library but at least it finds all the header files!

Comment: I found that the google-test problem was not flycheck itself, it was one of my checkers, cppcheck to be exact. I removed it from my system and are using clang instead.